# sqlsrv throwing errors when I connect to my PC's LocalHost via my laptop on the same network

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, localhost, sqlsrv

So, I have developed a search page on LocalHost that uses data from a MSSQL database, it works fine on my PC, with no errors occurring at all, however when I connect to my LocalHost via my IP address on my laptop which is connected to the same network as my PC I get the following error messages:

> **Warning**:sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in C:.........\ on line 47.
>
> **Warning**: sqlsrv_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in C:.........\ on line 76.
>
> **Warning**: sqlsrv_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in C:.........\ on line 94.

EDIT:

```
<?php require 'db_conn.php'?>
<?php
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your actual code? It seems, that the `sqlsrv_connect()` call returns `false`.

Comment: @Zhorov it returns true on my PC's LocalHost, however if I try to connect to the LocalHost on the PC from my Laptop it returns false. I'll add some code to the question.

Comment: You need to get some debug information: `<?php ... $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo); if ($conn === false) {echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); exit;} ... ?>`

Comment: Is SQL Server installed on your laptop? "localhost" always refers to the machine where the code is running.

Comment: @ADyson no it's on an external server.

Comment: ok so you need to change the connection string to point to the hostname or IP address of that server then. And ensure that the SQL Server instance on that server is set up to allow connections from other machines. If you connect to "localhost" from your laptop, it will attempt to connect to itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost . Unless I've misunderstood, but it sounded like your SQL Server connection string has "localhost" as the server to connect to? Or is that not what you mean? If not, you need to follow Zhorov's suggestion and get a proper error message.